# How to create a scroll able listView with chips

Tags: flutter

Please can someone tell me how to create a scrollable ListView with chips in. That point is to wrap the chips so they are all in the same line and they are scrollable when the user swipes.

This is my code so far, but it's not scrollable. How to make it horizontally scrollable?

```
class Filters extends StatefulWidget {
  final String chipName;

  Filters({Key key, this.chipName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FiltersState createState() => _FiltersState();
}

class _FiltersState extends State<Filters> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Wrap(

          children: <Widget>[
            filterChipWidget(chipName: 'General'),
            filterChipWidget(chipName: 'Welcome'),
            filterChipWidget(chipName: 'Recommendation'),
            filterChipWidget(chipName: 'Other'),
            filterChipWidget(chipName: 'My Friends'),
            filterChipWidget(chipName: 'Threads'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add SingelChildScrollView as parent of your Row, and make it horizontal.

Here code:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Wrap(

        children: <Widget>[
          filterChipWidget(chipName: 'General'),
          filterChipWidget(chipName: 'Welcome'),
          filterChipWidget(chipName: 'Recommendation'),
          filterChipWidget(chipName: 'Other'),
          filterChipWidget(chipName: 'My Friends'),
          filterChipWidget(chipName: 'Threads'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```